# Fetching user details from facebook in xcode 4.5 with ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook-login

I have implemented the concept of integration of facebook login in my app.
1----> I was able to do facebook login but after the user facebook login I want to continue with my app i.e a tabbarController with three tab items appears and simultaneously I need to fetch facebook user details (email,firstname,lastname etc)

But I was unable to retrieve details. I do not understand where I m going wrong.

In my ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender
{
    AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    SearchViewController *searchViewController=[[SearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];

    UserProfile *userprofile=[[UserProfile alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
    userprofile.title=@"My Profile";

    LogOut *logout=[[LogOut alloc]initWithNibName:@"LogOut" bundle:nil];

    logout.title=@"Log Out";
    tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController,userprofile,logout, nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(sessionStateChanged:)
                                                 name:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                           id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString *fbUserEmail= @"";

                 NSLog(@"%@",user);

                 fbUserEmail=[user objectForKey:@"email"];

                 AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                 appDelegate.fbEmail=fbUserEmail;
             }
         }
         ];
    }
}
```

But here without showing facebook login page I m getting tabbarController and I m unable to get retrieve user details.

How can I show facebook login page first and then tabbarController with user details.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch facebook user details by using Facebook Graph API, Below Link demonstrate the use of Graph API to get basic user details. Check here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Comment: Yes, Facebook has also updated their API for latest version of xcode and ios as well.